# How to quit Electron app on Mac?

Tags: macos, electron

Below is stock code from the Electron website (https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/):

```
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

On Mac OS 10.12.4, when the above is called, it will not close the app. Only the window. Adding `app.quit()` above the conditional does close the app. Did they leave something out specific to Mac OS X that prevents the app from closing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want to learn how to read comments in code. Here's the full excerpt from the page you linked:

```
// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

The two lines above the if-statement correlate to the if-statement. This basically says that we are **not** quitting the app on macOS *because* this is a common functionality found in other apps.

Comment: You are right. I've just never actually had a Mac app end up in a state where all windows are closed but the app is open. Almost seems like a no-op.

Comment: The apps will still exist on the dock, and there will be a menu bar at the top when they're in focus AFAIK. I haven't touched a Mac in a couple of years, so I'm not certain how Electron should gracefully handle that.

Comment: @4thSpace - most (all?) OSX apps allow all windows to be closed without exiting the app. It has been that way since forever. It is the "app as player" model.

Comment: 50 / 50 On mac, some apps stay in dock like "Safari, iTunes..." and some don't like "Photos, Notes..."